# user.valid_password of devise gem does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, rubygems, password-encryption

```
def create
user_password = params[:session][:password]
user_email = params[:session][:email]
user = user_email.present? && User.find_by(email: user_email)

if user and user.valid_password? user_password
  sign_in user
  user.generate_authentication_token!
  user.save
  render json: user, status: 200, location: [:api, user]

else
  #render json: { errors: "Invalid email or passwords"}, status: 422
  render json: { errors: "Invalid email or passwords"}, status: 422

end
```

end

not able to login after user has signed in,it seems the valid_password? method does not encrypt the password in same format as encrypted password stored in database by the devise,any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is proper for creating session. Just check if you're creating the user properly!

Do this in your rails console

```
User.create({email:"anything@gmail.com",password:"anything"})
User.find(type the id of new user).valid_password?("anything")
```

If this returns true then you are not creating the user properly. Check the method where you're creating the user.